# Can I use sourced files globally?

Tags: bash, shell

Consider this script excerpt:

tpl file content:

```
FULL_ACCESS_USER_TPL="id=FA_SEND action = OK sender == $EMAIL"
```

script content

```
source tpl

EMAILS="foo@domain.tld bar@domain.tld"

for EMAIL in $EMAILS
do
    echo $FULL_ACCESS_USER_TPL
done
```

Desired output:

```
id=FA_SEND action = OK sender == foo@domain.tld
id=FA_SEND action = OK sender == bar@domain.tld
```

When I run the script I get nothing, but if I put `source tpl` inside the loop for, I get what I want.

Can I source files, let's say, 'globally' in order to use them all over the script?

Comment: what's in `tpl`?

Comment: seems the scripts are not complete, because if `tpl` is sourced output can't be empty, while I don't understand the question, the path to script tpl should be absolute otherwise depends on current working directory

Comment: "When I run the script I get nothing" - not with the script you've posted.

Comment: I'm sorry for being messy. The content of tpl file is `FULL_ACCESS_USER_TPL="id=FA_SEND action = OK sender == $EMAIL"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function in tpl, then call the function:

```
$ cat tpl
function FULL_ACCESS_USER_TPL() {

    echo "id=FA_SEND action = OK sender == $EMAIL"
}

$ cat script.sh
source tpl

EMAILS="foo@domain.tld bar@domain.tld"

for EMAIL in $EMAILS
do
    FULL_ACCESS_USER_TPL
done
```

The problem was that, when you sourced tpl, `EMAIL` was not set.